# String to Date Format in PySpark 3.5

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

### Date

'2020/12/01'
20201227
'2020/12/03'
NULL
'2020-12-13'

In the date column, these kinds of data are available and I need to change the yyyy-MM-dd format
How we can achieve this in Pyspark.

Basically, when I use to_date it gives NULL.

When I used to_datetime() in panda its working fine but how its possible in pyspark